# How can I do multidimensional matrix multiplication in numpy, scipy

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, scipy

I have a scipy sparse matrix with shape (8,9) and another array with shape (9, 12 , 17). I want to multiply these such that I get a matrix/array of size (8,12,17) where the (8,9) matrix has effectively multiplied the first dimension only. Do I have to use Kronecker products to do this or is there a simple way in numpy?

Comment: And the output would be sparse too?

Comment: No, the output would be an array I guess.

Comment: So, convert to dense formats with `.todense()` and use `np.dot/np.tensordot`?

Comment: The result is 3d so can't be `scipy sparse`.  And 8x9 is too small to have any sparse advantage.  Go the dense array route.  I like `einsum`.

Comment: Those dimensions are hypothetical. They are really in the thousands.

Answer (score 2):

If `m1` is the 2d sparse matrix, `m1.A` is its dense array form.  The dinmensions practically write the `einsum` expression.

```
np.einsum('ij,jkl->ikl', m1.A, m2)
```

for example:

```
In [506]: M = sparse.random(8, 9, 0.1)
In [507]: A = np.ones((9, 12, 17))
In [508]: np.einsum('ij,jkl->ikl', M.A, A).shape
Out[508]: (8, 12, 17)
```

Answer (score 1):

As hpaulj suggests in the comments, the easiest way to do this is [`np.einsum`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html) with a dense matrix:

```
>>> a = np.random.randn(8, 9)
>>> b = np.random.randn(9, 12, 17)
>>> c = np.einsum('ij,jkl->ikl', a, b)
>>> c.shape
(8, 12, 17)
```

Answer (score 1):

@Divakar recommended `np.tensordot`, and @hpaulj and @Praveen suggested `np.einsum`. Yet another way is transposing axes:

```
(a @ b.transpose((2, 0, 1))).transpose((1, 2, 0))
```

For the small dimensions that you quote, `np.einsum` and transposition seem to be faster. But once you start scaling up the dimension of the axis along which you are multiplying, `np.tensordot` beats the other two.

```
import numpy as np

m, n, k, l = 8, 9, 12, 17
a = np.random.random((m, n))
b = np.random.random((n, k, l))

%timeit np.tensordot(a, b, axes=([1], [0]))
# => 10000 loops, best of 3: 22 µs per loop
%timeit np.einsum("ij,jkl->ikl", a, b)
# => 100000 loops, best of 3: 10.1 µs per loop
%timeit (a @ b.transpose((2, 0, 1))).transpose((1, 2, 0))
# => 100000 loops, best of 3: 11.1 µs per loop

m, n, k, l = 8, 900, 12, 17
a = np.random.random((m, n))
b = np.random.random((n, k, l))

%timeit np.tensordot(a, b, axes=([1], [0]))
# => 1000 loops, best of 3: 198 µs per loop
%timeit np.einsum("ij,jkl->ikl", a, b)
# => 1000 loops, best of 3: 868 µs per loop
%timeit (a @ b.transpose((2, 0, 1))).transpose((1, 2, 0))
# => 1000 loops, best of 3: 907 µs per loop

m, n, k, l = 8, 90000, 12, 17
a = np.random.random((m, n))
b = np.random.random((n, k, l))

%timeit np.tensordot(a, b, axes=([1], [0]))
# => 10 loops, best of 3: 21.7 ms per loop
%timeit np.einsum("ij,jkl->ikl", a, b)
# => 10 loops, best of 3: 164 ms per loop
%timeit (a @ b.transpose((2, 0, 1))).transpose((1, 2, 0))
# => 10 loops, best of 3: 166 ms per loop
```

Comment: `@` is `np.matmul` (if you don't have a new enough Python).  `help(np.matmul)` for docs.

Answer (score 0):

Here are a couple of ways I can get it to work. The second seems to be better and is about 12 times faster when I tested.

```
def multiply_3D_dim_zero_slow(matrix, array):
shape = array.shape
final_shape = (matrix.shape[0], array.shape[1], array.shape[2])
result = np.zeros(final_shape)
for i in xrange(shape[1]):
    for j in xrange(shape[2]):
        result[:, i, j] = matrix * array[:, i, j]
return result.reshape(final_shape)
```

And here is a faster version that uses reshape to make the multidimensional array into a 2D array.

```
def multiply_3D_dim_zero(matrix, array):
shape = array.shape
final_shape = (matrix.shape[0], array.shape[1], array.shape[2])
array_reshaped = array.reshape(shape[0], shape[1] * shape[2])
return (matrix * array_reshaped).reshape(final_shape)ode here
```

This just works on the first dimension which is what I need but one could generalize.

Comment: `tensordot` does this kind of reshaping so it can call `dot`.  It may also swapaxes to get them in the right order.